# C# Progress Bar in background worker + Socket - Progress bar only updates after socket comm is done

Tags: c#, sockets, backgroundworker

I am facing an issue with progress bar in background worker.

```
public void UpdateDevices(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     bw_1.RunWorkerAsync();
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     WebSwitchHandler.GetDeviceStats(NewRoom); 
    //Above line opnes a socket and takes 5 seconds to return back//
}

private void bw_1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      bw_1.ReportProgress(i);
   }
} 
private void bw_1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

The progress bar updates only after the socket has returned. The socket class has no threads, it blocks the entire gui for the 5 seconds.

Why doesnt this work? and suggestions how I should handle this with GUI.

Comment: shouldn't the function " WebSwitchHandler.GetDeviceStats(NewRoom); " be inside do work?

Comment: Simply if you want to run progress bar then you have to released the UI thread if their is prob in Progress bar that means your UI thread is busy in Process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, You need two background worker to achieve the GUI working for you with progress bar. one you already have to update the progress bar.

Second one you can use to call the `WebSwitchHandler.GetDeviceStats(NewRoom);` as async operation so that your UI thread doesn't get blocked. On completed of this BG worker you can notify the first one to finish immediately rather waiting for a fixed time always. This way you can also optimize your wait time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the progress bar is being updated by the UI thread. But the UI thread is "busy" waiting for the `GetDeviceStats` function to complete. So it cannot handle the progres bar update until it becomes free again.

If the `GetDeviceStats` function is a long running process (which to me it is) then you would be best including that work within you background worker thread. However, you still wont be able to report the progress (and therefore update the progress bar) until the call has once again finished.

Some possible solutions to that would be to either have `GetDeviceStats` report progress as it completes (I am not sure what that function actually does, so this may not be an option), OR if you need to "fake" the progress then use a second background thread or a timer.

Personally, I would just set the progress bar style to "Marquee" so the user knows the program is busy doing something, and then run the `GetDeviceStats` function on a single background worker.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I solved this on similar line - Implemented two bk_workers -> 1 that calls the function GetDeviceStats and 2 that updates the progress bar, When the first bk_worker completes it calls the bk_worker_2.cancelasync() and reports 100 progress